# How do I Auto-Parallelize Heap Arrays?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, performance, parallel-processing, x86

I'm trying to write a function that multiplies an array on the heap by a constant, using a parallel for loop, but when attepting to compile in VisualStudio 2017 with /Qpar-report:2 set, I get the message "Loop not parallelized due to reason '1000'.  I looked it up and the message is "The compiler detected a data dependency in the loop body.":

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/vectorizer-and-parallelizer-messages?view=vs-2017#BKMK_ReasonCode100x

The text describes situations where (for example) different passes are dependent on the results of other passes, but that doesn't apply here.  The only situation I can think of is the optimizer might be worried that the two arrays overlap in memory, but how do you convince the compiler that's not the case?

I tried forcing it using the #pragma ivdep statement and the code compiles but the function hangs when it's called.

After much troubleshooting, I determined that if I create dummy arrays on the stack inside the function and loop over them, it parallelizes successfully.  Unfortunately, I can't rely on the arrays I'll be accepting to be small enough to be copied entirely onto the stack.

I checked SO and google for other examples of executing simple array operations like this in parallel, and they all use stack-allocated arrays.  Surely there's a clean way to parallelize an operation on a heap array??

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
#include "../UnitsConversion/UnitsConversion.h"

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

#define ARRAY_SIZE 10000000

double* testInD;
double* testOutD;

namespace UnitTest
{

TEST_CLASS(Parallel)
{
public:

    TEST_CLASS_INITIALIZE(setup) {
        testInD = new double[ARRAY_SIZE];
        testOutD = new double[ARRAY_SIZE];

        for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
            testInD[i] = (double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
            testOutD[i] = (double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
        }

    }

    TEST_CLASS_CLEANUP(cleanup) {
        delete testInD;
        delete testOutD;
    }

    TEST_METHOD(PressuresD)
    {
        Assert::AreEqual(
            (int)1,
            PressureD(
                testInD,
                testOutD,
                ARRAY_SIZE
            )
        );
    }

}

int __stdcall PressureD(
    double* dblInValue,
    double* dblOutValue,
    int n) {

#pragma loop(hint_parallel(0))
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    dblOutValue[i] = dblInValue[i] * 5.0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

For whatever reason I'm not having any luck finding a solution with Google or SO, even though I'd think this would be a common problem.  Am I missing something?

EDIT:

Changing the loop to the following does allow it to parallelize:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    //dblOutValue[i] = dblInValue[i] * factor; (old version)
    dblOutValue[i] *= factor;
}
```

However, when I attempt to run the unit test, the code hangs and eventually (after about 15 seconds) aborts.  The code works when I run it in debug mode, but I'm 95% sure that's because it's not paralellizing when run in debug.

Comment: Have you tried `__restrict`?

Comment: I'd not heard of that keyword!  I tried it, and the code did parallelize when compiled, but the unit test still hangs and eventually aborts when I run it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple new/delete mismatch.  Your unit test has array `new[]` and scalar `delete`.

Ditch the manual memory management and use either `std::unique_ptr<double[]>` or `std::vector<double>`.  You may need to grab a bare pointer to your data before looping (in fact, `PressureD` doesn't need to change at all), in order for parallelization to succeed, but you don't need to manually manage the lifetime.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on using vectors.  I tried swapping my array declaration out to `std::vector<double> testInD(ARRAY_SIZE);` and the pointer in the function call to `&testInD[0]`, but the test is still aborting.

Comment: @Porksodaguy: Ok, it might be time to debug an optimized (aka release) build